# Avoid PyCharm warning when chaining methods of subclass of Django QuerySet

Tags: python, django, pycharm, django-queryset, python-typing

Consider following example code:

```
class MyQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def my_method(self):
        return self.annotate(_something=47)
    
    def my_method_2(self):
        return self.annotate(_something2=42)

    def second_method(self):
        return self.my_method().my_method_2()
```

Problem is that *PyCharm*s type checker highlights `my_method_2()` call ("*Unresolved attribute reference 'my_method_2' for class 'QuerySet'*", strong warning). I could disable warning inside IDE on case-by-case basis but that does not sound right.

Is this only bug in IDE, or is there some way to annotate the code so that *PyCharm* will understand that my methods return `MyQuerySet` so everything is fine? PyCharm usually doesn't complain about things it couldn't infer.

Comment: "ype-checker is right, types do not match" => did you check this ? I'm afraid your typechecker is wrong - all your methods of course return `MyQuerySet` instances - else the code wouldn't work indeed, and custom querysets would actually be of very limited use ;-)

Comment: You are right. So my assumption is wrong. But I don't understand why it complains then. Usually if method is not defined, it does not complain because it's Python and it's expected to use things defined during runtime. I'm going to look into this and then edit or delete the queston.

Comment: You probably figured out by now, but the problem is that your method is named `my_method_2`, not `my_method2`.

Comment: I have edited the question. It was just typo, I have created this minimal example based on real_world example, it showed right error on the right place, so I didn't notice the typo.